# Reducing Node + Express + Socket.io memory usage when using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, socket.io

I'm using Node + Express (running locally) and connecting to a MongoDB hosted on MongoDB Atlas. My project is a behemoth that started a while back using MDN's Local Library tutorial, and it grew as I learned how to use Express, sockets, mongo, etc. So some code in it is very bad, some is less so. Now, with a mostly feature-ready product, it's having high memory usage when multiple people connect.

Using Artillery, I have 5 users/second hit my /join_session endpoint for 20 seconds. This spikes memory usage from ~35MB to ~450MB. Full disclosure, I'm terrible at reading Chrome's Node.js Devtools for memory usage. But here's what I see under system/Context:

| Object | Origin | Distance | Shallow Size | Retained Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| this::ConnectionPool @2726315 | connection_pool.js:147 | 17 | 184 0% | 351324152 79% |
| ::Denque @3436241 | index.js:6 | 18 | 56 0% | 351320592 79% |
| _list::Array @3436499 |  | 19 | 32 0% | 351320536 79% |

That array has 1024 elements.
[Here's the statistics tab from Chrome's inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88fIT.png)

So it seems like mongoose's connection pool is the problem. I haven't changed my pool size, so that's the default of 5. I set up my connection in an external file that I `require` in App.js.

**App.js**

`require("./mongo.js");`

**mongo.js**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

var mongoDB = process.env.mongo;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  w: "majority",
  family: 4,
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.on(
  "error",
  console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:")
);

module.exports = mongoose;
```

I then access mongo like this:
`Session.findOne({ code: theCode }).exec(function (err, curSession) {`
And then do some fairly intensive tasks on the returned session, checking to see if the user has already joined, if they joined before they logged in, etc.

Then I call my custom socketAPI

```
socketAPI.getSession({code: curSession.code});
```

This also calls `Session.findOne({ code: data.code }).exec(function (err, curSession) {` and then communicates the names of all the users to all the people who use that same code. This is necessary because `socketAPI.getSession` also gets called from other places in the code that haven't just looked up the Session.

There's a lot in here and my next step is going to be to write a new function from the ground up to see if I can find the exact thing in all this mess that causes a massive memory spike. I'll update this question as I go.

UPDATE:
This code causes a memory spike from ~35MB to more than 450MB:

```
router.post("/test", function (req, res) {
  console.log("1: Calling test function");
  Session.findOne({ code: req.body.code }).exec(function (err, curSession) {
    console.log("2: Found session");
    curSession.save(function (err) {
      console.log("3: saved session");
      User.findOne({ profile_id: curSession.users[0].user })
        .select({ profile_id: 1, name: 1 })
        .exec(function (err, curUsers) {
          console.log("4: Got user");
        });
    });
  });
  res.send({ status: "tested!" });
});
```

Removing levels of callback one at a time progressively reduces memory usage.

**EDIT2: More Updates**

I have definitely isolated *a* memory issue. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Run `express memory-test` in a new directory.
2. Add the following lines to app.js

**App.js**

```
Line 1: require("dotenv").config();

Line 12: var mongoose = require("mongoose");

Line 14: 
var mongoDB = process.env.mongo;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  w: "majority",
  family: 4,
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.on(
  "error",
  console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:")
);
```

3. Add the following to index.js after `router.get("/")`

**Index.js**

```
router.post("/test", function (req, res) {
  console.log("1: Calling test function");
  Session.findOne({ code: req.body.code }).exec(function (err, curSession) {
    console.log("2: Found session");
    curSession.save(function () {
      console.log("3: saved session");
      User.findOne({ profile_id: curSession.users[0].user })
        .select({ profile_id: 1, name: 1 })
        .exec(function (err, curUsers) {
          console.log("4: Got user");
          res.send({ status: "tested!" });
        });
    });
  });
});
```

4. Run `npm install` and also install `mongoose`, `dotenv`, and `artillery`
5. Create a .env file with `mongo=mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER/DATABASE?retryWrites=true`. My database has the following relevant collections:

| Name | Documents | Total size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| users | 17 | 188.05KB |
| sessions | 10142 | 2.21MB |

6. Add Schemas for Users and Sessions
7. Create `test.yaml` with the following test:

```
config:
  target: "http://dev.tts:3000"
  phases:
    - duration: 20
      arrivalRate: 10
scenarios:
  - flow:
      - post:
          url: "/test"
          json:
            code: "H5PQW"
            voteArray:
              - game: 5f272c2a7cd31f4b4c0e72c7
                vote: "771"
              - game: 5f4fe877f205cde8c05f2c48
                vote: "500"
              - game: 5f272c6b7cd31f4b4c0e8128
                vote: "500"
      - think: 10
```

With these steps taken, this test will result in total memory usage of 1200+MB and a total runtime of 2-4 minutes before the memory is deallocated when the test ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out, the memory usage on the above test isn't that far off of normal. It's about 6MB per client, which isn't the worst, I just need a better server if I expect ~200 concurrent clients, and in particular I need more than the free tier of mongo cloud to serve DB requests more quickly. In production, the real memory spike I was seeing had NOTHING to do with the above. Instead, it was because I was repeatedly fetching an entire collection with ~10k records, each of which was a JSON object with props. Parsing that takes lots of memory, really fast, and will need to be the subject of a different post!